# XPath doesn't recognize path

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm writing an XSL transformer to convert XML to HTML. Here's my **gun.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="guns.xslt"?>
<guns xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="guns2.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <gun>
        <model>revolver</model>
        <handy>1</handy>
        <origin>Britain</origin>
        <ttc>20mm</ttc>
    </gun>
</guns>
```

And **guns.xslt** here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match = "/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Gun Collection</h2>
                <table border = "1">
                    <tr bgcolor = "#9acd32">
                        <th>Model</th>
                        <th>Origin</th>
                        <th>TTC</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="guns/gun">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select = "model"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select = "handy"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select = "origin"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select = "ttc"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both files are located in the same package, but XPAth doesn't recognize `"guns/gun"` in `for-each` block. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared in xml-stylesheet - type as "text/xsl", please change file extension from "guns.xslt" to "guns.xsl" and also change in your XML as below:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="guns.xsl"?>
```

Then your result will be as below:

[image]